# PayPal Order Creation with Smart Button - (React/NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, paypal

[React/NodeJS] I'm having a huge struggle in finding the appropriate documentation on this topic -- I am looking to implement PayPal on my website, with the constraint being that the customer is charged after our offline service is completed (has variable costs, but there is something of a solution in mind such that if I can 'authorize' an amount equal to our maximum cost that we will be a-okay). My initial research indicated to me that PayPal Orders fulfill this desire, to at least an effective extent, ie. the order is placed and funds are not placed on hold until we authorize the charge, ideally after the offline service is completed (source: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payments/orders/#order-response). Upon further inspection, I have discovered that the integration path using PayPal smart buttons is being heavily advocated in implementation docs and appear to be compatible with the orders API (source: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/).

I began working to implement the software, following the smart buttons implementation linked just prior, and followed the instruction to use server side api calls to process the payment (source: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/ and https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/set-up-transaction/). Continuing forward, I pursued order creation explicitly using the orders API (mistake perhaps?) and used the docs for the v2 orders api and the docs for the nodeJs sdk package referenced in the paypal docs (paypal/checkout-server-sdk using the github docs). I set up the integration and the sandbox accounts showed that charges were being placed however, and this was contradictory to my desire to not place charges on hold until an authorization is completed. The status returned on the backend is kept at "created", so I was initially optimistic, but the charge placement was unfortunate.

I am struggling to find the next step. As the checkout-server-sdk is utilizing both payments/v2 and orders/v2 (source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@paypal/checkout-server-sdk), I  am lead to believe I can utilize those API endpoints as well, but can't find explicit functions that call the payments api in question in the checkout-server-sdk, which I believe I would need to change order intent in order to create an order (source: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payments/orders/), but also noticed these docs (linked as active directly from the docs page for paypal I believe -- https://developer.paypal.com/docs/ ) post to payments/v1 (source: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payments/orders/) which has been deprecated. Long story short, I am now lost and would thoroughly appreciate some guidance on where I walked astray, what docs to refer to, if this implementation is still supported, and potentially what the next step is. If I used incorrect verbiage or have some noticeable jump in logic that was to my detriment, I would love to know as I am fairly new to developer work as a whole. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your use-case of not placing a temporary hold up front requires `intent:order`, and only the v1/orders API has this available.  The v2/* APIs do not.

An `intent:authorize` hold typically clears from a card after about ~3 days (even though it is capturable up til day 29), so I would recommend using the v2 APIs if that's workable. But if it's important to not do that, then v1/orders can be used. The API is not going to disappear, people are using it. Even-yet-older Classic APIs with similar PAYMENTACTION=ORDER functionality are still in heavy use, after all.